# error: linker `link.exe` not found (VS BuildTools installed)

Tags: rust, compiler-errors

Code:

```
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

Output:

```
C:/Users/lennard/.cargo/bin/cargo.exe build --color=always --message-format=json-diagnostic-rendered-ansi --package untitled --bin untitled
   Compiling untitled v0.1.0 (C:\Users\lennard\CLionProjects\untitled)
error: linker `link.exe` not found
  |
  = note: program not found

note: the msvc targets depend on the msvc linker but `link.exe` was not found

note: please ensure that Visual Studio 2017 or later, or Build Tools for Visual Studio were installed with the Visual C++ option.

note: VS Code is a different product, and is not sufficient.

error: aborting due to previous error

error: could not compile `untitled` (bin "untitled") due to 2 previous errors
Process finished with exit code 101`
```

I've installed the VS Build Tools with the "Desktop development with C++"... I am able to find various link.exe manually:

- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\bin\Hostx64\x86\link.exe`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\bin\Hostarm64\x86\link.exe`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\bin\Hostarm64\x64\link.exe`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\bin\Hostx86\x64\link.exe`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\bin\Hostx86\x86\link.exe`

[image]

Comment: What version of Windows? Try installing the Windows 11 and/or Windows 10 SDK. This person had a similar issue: https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/txkzpa/does_it_work_with_vs_2022_build_toolswindows_11/

Comment: Also related: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-install-rust-microsoft-c-build-tools-on-windows-without-msdn-license/65896/4

Comment: @PitaJ Thx... Using Windows 11... installed Win 10, Win 11 SDK, MSVC 143 (VS2022), 142 (VS2019) and C++ CMake tools for Windows. Error still occurs :/

Comment: It probably means that `link.exe` isn't added to your `PATH` environment variable. Try adding the one you need (what platform you want to compile your program to) to the `PATH`. Here's [how to add it](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/)

Comment: Or alternatively, you can modify the `linker` option in `C:\Users\YourUser\.cargo\config.toml` (use absolute path to link.exe). (More about config.toml: https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html)

Comment: Ok... I wasn't accidentally using CLion x86_64 via translation layer instead of the native ARM64 version... now link.exe can be found, but now it gives me this error instead:
  = note: LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'kernel32.lib'
PS: Yes 'kernel32.lib' does exist on my system

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've finally solved the issue  by setting up a new clean VM, installed Desktop development with C++, ran the rustup-init and now it compiles without further errors.

No idea what caused the previous issues.